# I want to do translate, rotate and scale while merging the two textures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all, please understand that sentences may not be smooth using a translator.

I'm going to combine the two textures and create them into one texture.

Example) [1. image__](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcI3F.png)      [2. image__](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNvOd.png)     [3. result__](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0KKb.png)

A simple combination of two textures is not a problem.
The problem is that translate, rotate and scale should be applied to one texture and merged, but I can't think of a way. I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

here my code :

```
Texture2D CombineTexutes(Texture2D _textureA, Texture2D _textureB, int startX = 0, int startY = 0)
{
    //Create new textures
    Texture2D textureResult = new Texture2D(_textureA.width, _textureA.height);
    //create clone form texture
    textureResult.SetPixels(_textureA.GetPixels());
    //Now copy texture B in texutre A
    for (int x = startX; x < _textureB.width + startX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = startY; y < _textureB.height + startY; y++)
        {
            Color c = _textureB.GetPixel(x - startX, y - startY);
            if (c.a > 0.0f) //Is not transparent
            {
                //Copy pixel colot in TexturaA
                textureResult.SetPixel(x, y, c);
            }
        }
    }

    //Apply colors
    textureResult.Apply();
    return textureResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively tricky with pixel transformations. You would have to read up on various algorithms for every of those tasks.
A much easier solution would be to use game objects with sprite renderers and then render everything onto a "render texture" (if you really need a texture).
Game objects with a sprite renderer can be easily rotated, scaled etc.

Your result image does look as if it was actually deforming the sprite though, not just scaled in a direction.
If that's your goal, then I'd recommend looking at the Animation 2D package. That allows you to do near anything with sprites.